# HTML float property not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a tabs for my page, but my links are not appearing horizontally. I have used float:left which is used to make links appear horizontally. Please let me know why?

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            #navbar #holder ul {
               list-style: none;
               margin: 0;
               padding:0;           
                 }

            #navbar #holder ul li a {
            text-decoration:none;
            float: left;
            line-height:20px;
            margin-right:5px;
            font-family:Calibri;
            color:#000;
        }

     </style>
   </head>

  <body bgcolor="SteelBlue">
     <div id="navbar">
        <div id="holder">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Mixers</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Others</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: It works in IE. Which browser(s) are you testing with? Try moving the "float:left" to the li element instead of the a.

Comment: Your code seems to work perfecty fine. Here's a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/Lujp9k15/

Comment: The OP's code _can_ work, if no CSS or browser defaults give the li element some height. Have amended my answer with more detail

Answer (score 2):

The float left property needs to be applied to the Li element.

In your code it is being applied to the a element *within* the Li.

This can work, but if the parent element has any height (or if `overflow:hidden` is applied to it), they will stack up underneath each other and the starting position for the child elements will be on the left, so `float:left` won't change their position.

It might be easier to think of the list elements as being for layout and positioning, and the anchor element for visual appearance.

```
#navbar #holder ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

#navbar #holder ul li {
    float:left;
}


#navbar #holder ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:20px;
    margin-right:5px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The links are appearing horizontally for me:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nv8e7cbg/)

Are you viewing the links in a small viewport?
Also, what browser are you using?

It is also more common for the `float: left` property to be applied to the `li` element, not the enclosed `a` element.